# Is there anywhere I can get a complete list of historical Safari release notes?

Tags: safari

I’ve done a bit of searching for specific Safari version numbers in support.apple.com. Quite a few versions have specific change notes, but it seems like often the versions bundled with major OS X releases aren’t given their own change notes.

- 1.0: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2964

  - 1.2: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL612 (Dave Hyatt also provided some more detailed notes on the old WebKit blog: http://weblogs.mozillazine.org/hyatt/archives/2004_02.html#004874)
  - 1.3.1: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL445
  - 1.3.2: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL403
- 2.0.1: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL444
- 3.1: http://support.apple.com/kb/TA25197?viewlocale=en_US

  - 3.1.1: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL78
  - 3.2.1: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL723
  - 3.2.3: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL820
- 4.0.5: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL877

  - 4.1: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1045
  - 4.1.2: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1069
- 5.0: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1046

  - 5.0.2: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1070

Also, sometimes Apple’s release notes can be a bit... terse.

I’m trying to figure out which versions of Safari introduced support for HTML5/CSS features.

[Wikipedia’s got a great table of releases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history), but it is a bit vague on CSS improvements (e.g. “improved CSS support”).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Safari uses Webkit as it's rendering engine. If you're specifically looking for when it began to support HTML5/CSS3, it as a fully open-source repository where you can review changes commit by commit. As such, you can see the full comprehensive, intricately detailed history here: http://trac.webkit.org/timeline

Comment: The problem with that approach is that commits don't say when they each made it into which shipping version of Safari.

Comment: @Dori - Ah yes, fair point. Hadn't considered that small but important issue!

Comment: @Dori @Chops: That said, [the Wikipedia Safari version history page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history) gives WebKit version numbers for each Safari release, and some of the commit messages in Trac seem to refer to tags for these WebKit version numbers (see e.g. http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/9369). So it might be possible to retrospectively construct CSS-focused release notes from that.

Answer (score 3):

The Wapedia table you point to appears to just be a less clear version of the [Safari version history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history) page on Wikipedia.

[This particular search](http://caniuse.com/#agents=webkit_saf&cats=HTML5,CSS3) on "When can I use…" appears to display much of what you're looking for.

[This page at findmebyip.com](http://fmbip.com/litmus#target-selector) also has a good breakdown, although it's not as specific about particular browser versions.

Comment: Ah yes, I thought the Wapedia stuff felt a bit Wikipedia-y, I hadn’t noticed the separate Wikipedia page for Safari history. Question updated.

Comment: When Can I Use and Find Me By IP are getting there, but the former only goes back to 3.2, and the latter only appears to have information on 4 and 5. I’m looking to find out when support for features was introduced, so this only covers stuff that was introduced recently.

Answer (score 1):

This website may help you:

http://caniuse.com/

Comment: Kind of — I’m more looking for a per-version list of every HTML/CSS feature for which support was added, for each released version of Safari. So something like Safari 2: `<video>` tag; Safari 3: `<audio>` tag and CSS Transforms. Bit hard to reverse-engineer that from caniuse.com.